# Tensorflow NN accuracy/predictions not changing

Tags: python, tensorflow

Attempting to create a NN with Tensorflow that predicts whether or not an NBA shot was made but the model seems to just predict that the shot misses every time and the accuracy does not change from epoch to epoch.

I'm not sure whether or not it is due to the data itself or the gradient descent function. It worked with the iris dataset and cannot figure out what changes when the data changed.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd

RANDOM_SEED = 42
tf.set_random_seed(RANDOM_SEED)


def init_weights(shape):
    """ Weight initialization """
    weights = tf.random_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(weights)

def forwardprop(X, w_1, w_2):
    """
    Forward-propagation.
    IMPORTANT: yhat is not softmax since TensorFlow's softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits() does that internally.
    """
    h    = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X, w_1))  # The \sigma function
    yhat = tf.matmul(h, w_2)  # The \varphi function
    return yhat

def get_iris_data():
    """ Read the iris data set and split them into training and test sets """
    my_data = pd.read_csv("shot_logs.csv").sample(2000)
    my_data["GAME_CLOCK"] = pd.to_numeric(my_data["GAME_CLOCK"].str.split(":").str[0]) * 60 + pd.to_numeric(
        my_data["GAME_CLOCK"].str.split(":").str[1])
    my_data["LOCATION"] = my_data["LOCATION"].map({
        "A":0,
        "H":1
    })

    data   = my_data[["LOCATION", "SHOT_NUMBER", "PERIOD", "GAME_CLOCK", "SHOT_CLOCK", "DRIBBLES", "TOUCH_TIME",
                   "SHOT_DIST", "CLOSE_DEF_DIST"]]
    target = my_data["FGM"]

    # Prepend the column of 1s for bias
    N, M  = data.shape
    all_X = np.ones((N, M + 1))
    all_X[:, 1:] = data

    # Convert into one-hot vectors
    num_labels = len(np.unique(target))
    print(num_labels)
    print(np.eye(num_labels))
    all_Y = np.eye(num_labels)[target]  # One liner trick!
    return train_test_split(all_X, all_Y, test_size=0.33, random_state=RANDOM_SEED)

def main():
    train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = get_iris_data()

    # Layer's sizes
    x_size = train_X.shape[1]   # Number of input nodes: 4 features and 1 bias
    h_size = 256                # Number of hidden nodes
    y_size = train_y.shape[1]   # Number of outcomes (3 iris flowers)
    print(y_size)

    # Symbols
    X = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, x_size])
    y = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, y_size])

    # Weight initializations
    w_1 = init_weights((x_size, h_size))
    w_2 = init_weights((h_size, y_size))

    # Forward propagation
    yhat    = forwardprop(X, w_1, w_2)
    predict = tf.argmax(yhat, axis=1)

    # Backward propagation
    cost    = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=yhat))
    updates = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(cost)

    # Run SGD
    sess = tf.Session()
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)

    for epoch in range(100):
        # Train with each example
        for i in range(len(train_X)):
            sess.run(updates, feed_dict={X: train_X[i: i + 1], y: train_y[i: i + 1]})

        train_accuracy = np.mean(np.argmax(train_y, axis=1) ==
                                 sess.run(predict, feed_dict={X: train_X, y: train_y}))
        test_accuracy  = np.mean(np.argmax(test_y, axis=1) ==
                                 sess.run(predict, feed_dict={X: test_X, y: test_y}))

        print("Epoch = %d, train accuracy = %.2f%%, test accuracy = %.2f%%"
              % (epoch + 1, 100. * train_accuracy, 100. * test_accuracy))

    sess.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is what the output is looking like:

```
Epoch = 1, train accuracy = 54.85%, test accuracy = 54.55%
Epoch = 2, train accuracy = 54.85%, test accuracy = 54.55%
Epoch = 3, train accuracy = 54.85%, test accuracy = 54.55%
Epoch = 4, train accuracy = 54.85%, test accuracy = 54.55%
Epoch = 5, train accuracy = 54.85%, test accuracy = 54.55%
Epoch = 6, train accuracy = 54.85%, test accuracy = 54.55%
Epoch = 7, train accuracy = 54.85%, test accuracy = 54.55%
Epoch = 8, train accuracy = 54.85%, test accuracy = 54.55%
Epoch = 9, train accuracy = 54.85%, test accuracy = 54.55%
Epoch = 10, train accuracy = 54.85%, test accuracy = 54.55%
Epoch = 11, train accuracy = 54.85%, test accuracy = 54.55%
```